# How to catch C2DM notice coming to the phone?

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

Is it possible for android enabled phone to intercept all C2DM notifications? If so, which way should dig.

Comment: can you provide intention to do this?

Comment: Yes, our client has a need to develop an alternate notice informer for c2dm (push) Message

Answer (score 0):

Few days back the announcement came that C2DM will be officially deprecated.

At that time C2DM stopped accepting new users and quota requests.

C2DM has been replaced by Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM). The C2DM service will continue to be maintained in the short term, but developers must use GCM for new development.

So in near feature we may need to move existing C2DM applications to GCM to take advantage of GCM features.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to intercept C2DM or GCM messages. The system won't deliver them to your interceptor. They are not delivered via an unsecured Broadcast Intent.